# Pictures on my Android phone's SD card do not show when connected to my PC

Tags: android, sd-card

The phone is LG X Screen

The only pictures that show up on the computer are the ones taken by my phone's camera (since I changed where it saves pictures from internal memory to sd card.)

I used an app called "Files To SD Card" to transfer some pics from internal storage to my SD card. Now when I open my phone on my pc I have

- Android
- DCIM
- LOST.DIR (which is empty)
- Gallery (file)
- Kik (file)

Kik was the name of one of the folders I transfered from internal storage to SD Card.

The "Gallery" file is 0 byte and was created today.

The "kik" file is 32 kB and was also created today (same time as the 'Gallery' file).